# Op-amp analysis with capacitor

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc, circuit-analysis

I have the next exercise:

[image: Circuit]

I proceed as follows (assuming ideal op-amp):

$$C = 2 \mu F$$
$$R_{1} = 50k \Omega$$
$$R_{2}=10k \Omega$$
$$v_{2} = 0V$$

For \$t>0\$:

- Node \$v1\$:

$$i_{s}=C \frac{d(v1-v2)}{dt}+ \frac{v1-v2}{R_{1}}$$
$$ \implies i_{s}=C \frac{dv1}{dt}+\frac{v1}{R_{1}}$$

- Node \$v2\$:

$$ C \frac{dv1}{dt}+ \frac{v1}{R_{1}} = \frac{v2-v_{o}}{R_{2}}$$
$$ \implies R_{2}C \frac{dv1}{dt}+ \frac{R_{2}}{R_{1}}v1 = -v_{o}$$

Solving for \$v_{o}\$ using last nodal equations:

$$v_{o}(t) = -i_{s}R_{2}=-100mV$$

Based on book answers, \$v_{o}(t)=100(2e^{-10t}-1)mV\$. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the "tricks" I've taught in EE fundamentals class is that placing a network in series with a current source *changes the voltage across the current source **only***.

(This is most easily seen by enclosing the network inside a supernode and applying KCL - the current entering the supernode is the current from the current source and this must equal the current leaving the supernode.)

Thus, the solution for \$v_o(t)\$ is unchanged by replacing the RC network with a wire and then it is clear that this circuit is a [current-to-voltage converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current-to-voltage_converter#Operation-amplifier_implementation) with trans-resistance:

$$R_M = -10k \Omega $$

and so,

$$v_o(t) = -i_s(t) \cdot 10k\Omega$$

The answer given by the book is clearly not for the circuit as drawn.

Comment: Another question: Is it the current among 10k resistor constant? Does affect capacitor charging period the current (attenuate it) and force a variable output current from 50k resistor and capacitor? It could explain exponential behavior given by the book answer -I guess-.

Comment: @Chuz, the current through (from left to right) the 10k resistor is precisely equal to the source current.  That's the crucial point I tried to make in my answer.  The details of the current through the capacitor are *irrelevant* since the current leaving the network must equal the current entering the network and this is just the source current.

Comment: Totally correct - maybe the error is that the input is a voltage source?

Comment: @Andyaka well, we have only the book diagram but possibly you have reason

Comment: @Andyaka, I considered that but then discarded that idea since, for a voltage source step input, the initial source current would be infinite as would be the initial output voltage.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a trick question to me and I don't agree with the answer given. I think you have the right answer but you didn't need to do so much work to get it. Since the op amp uses negative feedback and we assume that it is functioning properly, the voltage at \$v_2\$ must be the same as the voltage at the non-inverting input, which is grounded. So the op amp sees ground at both of its inputs.

Now we have to apply KCL at the \$v_2\$ junction. \$10\mu\$A enters from the left. No current flows into the op amp inputs, so the same current must flow from left to right through the \$10\$ kilohm resistor. By Ohm's theory that means that the output voltage must be \$-0.1\$V

The counterintuitive part of the problem is that the voltage at \$v_1\$ does not matter.

I'm guessing that there is a mistake in the figure, and that either the \$50\$ kilohm resistor or the capacitor should have been connected to ground instead of the op amp input. Can you cite a source for the problem? Who wrote the book?

Comment: I got it from "Fundamentals of electric circuit" Charles Alexander, N.O. Sadiku 5ed

Comment: The answer is included in a solution manual provided by the same book editorial :)